# Como é que posso ter um Radio Group com 10 radio buttons divididos em 2 colunas e 5 linhas?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Como é possível fazer isto? Tentei com `table row`, mas isso tira as propriedades do `radio group`.

Queria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai pegando os `RadioButtons` e colocando e copiando eles, com ctrl+c e ctrl+v, eles vão manter o grupo e criar uma seleção entre eles. Quando quiser pegar outro grupo, vai na toolbox e pega um novo RadioButton, e repita o procedimento, funciona comigo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um [`Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [`GroupBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) para agrupar os [`RadioButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx).
Veja um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]